# React native initial region not updating with state

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I have below code base

```
 componentDidMount() {
        //firebase.firestore().collection('locations').doc('test').set({ test: 'test' })

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                if (position) {

                    this.setState({
                      region: {
                        latitude: Number(position.coords.latitude),
                        longitude: Number(position.coords.longitude),
                        latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.003,
                      },
                    });
                  }
                  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.region))
            },
            (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 100 }
        );
        this.unsubscribe = this.locationRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollectionData);
       // firebase.firestore().collection("locations").get().then(QuerySnapshot => {  });
    }
```

And Map

```
  render() {
        return (<View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
          }}>
            <HeaderNavigationBar {...this.props} />
            <MapView showsUserLocation={true}
                // ref={map => this.map = map}
                initialRegion={this.state.region}
                style={styles.container}
            >
                {this.state.AllLocations.map((marker, index) => (
                    <MapView.Marker key={index}
                        coordinate={marker.locations.coords}
                        title={marker.Title}
                    />
                ))}
            </MapView>
          </View>);

    }
```

componentDidMount is correcty updating the state, but map is not showing correct position,it is taking as it was set in construction

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.locationRef = firebase.firestore().collection('locations');
        this.unsubscribe = null;
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            AllLocations: [],
            region: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                longitudeDelta: 0.003,
            }
        };
    }
```

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

initialRegion is used for the initial render of map.
In your case, You are getting the user location after your map render, Thats the reason its not getting updated.

To counter this there are two ways.

1: use a loading state till you get your use location, and prevent the map render before you get the location.

2: Use `region`, for example `region = {this.state.region}`.

```
<MapView showsUserLocation={true}
                // ref={map => this.map = map}
                initialRegion={this.state.region}
                region={this.state.region}
                style={styles.container}
            >
                {this.state.AllLocations.map((marker, index) => (
                    <MapView.Marker key={index}
                        coordinate={marker.locations.coords}
                        title={marker.Title}
                    />
                ))}
            </MapView>
```

Both will work, it depends on your usecase.

Comment: I added region={this.state.region}, but still no effect

Comment: The issue is with location probably, make sure you are getting the location for your geolocation api, It doesn't work well on many phones, and you can try a loading state till you get a location.

Comment: I am getting geolocation correctly i checked by placing an alert

Comment: Yes  adding the region property doesn't work. Location is being captured correctly. Anyone found answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{this.state.region ? (<MapView


                    style={[styles.map]}
                    initialRegion={this.state.region}
                    region={this.state.region}


                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}


                >


                    {this.state.AllLocations.map((marker, index) => (
                    <MapView.Marker key={index}
                        coordinate={marker.locations.coords}
                        title={marker.Title}
                    />
                ))}
                </MapView>) : (
                        <MapView
                            loadingEnabled={true}
                            style={styles.map}
                            showsMyLocationButton={true}
                            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                            style={[styles.map]}
                        >
                        </MapView>
                    )
                }
```

Set `region: null` in the constructor it will work

Comment: This works. I created a separate function and did this.